# Mutate within a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```html
structure(list(a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 1), b = c(1, 3, 4, 
2, 6, 7, 2, 6), c = c(6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3), d = c(6, 2, 4, 
5, 3, 7, 2, 6), e = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 3), f = c(2, 3, 4, 
2, 2, 7, 5, 2)), .Names = c("Love_ABC", "Love_CNN", "Hate_ABC", "Hate_CNN", "Love_CNBC", "Hate_CNBC"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have made the following for loop

```html
channels = c("ABC", "CNN", "CNBC")

for (channel in channels) { 
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  mutate(ALL_channel = Love_channel + Hate_channel)
  }
```

But when i run the for loop R tells me " object Love_channel" not found. Have i done something wrong in the for loop?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Three new columns "ALL_CNN", "ALL_ABC", "ALL_CNBC" where each row correspond to the sum of the corresponding love_channel+hate_channel.
For exampel, ALL_CNN = Love_CNN+Hate_CNN

Comment: Do you have `Love_channel` and `Hate_channel` columns in your data? I don't see them.

Comment: no i have Love_ABC and Hate_ABC but I made a for loop over channels = c("ABC", "CNN", "CNBC") an and indicated : for channel in channels

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column()

dataframe %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowid, names_to = c(NA, "channel"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = channel, names_prefix = "ALL_", values_from = value, values_fn = sum) %>% 
  right_join(dataframe, by = "rowid") %>% 
  select(-rowid)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 9
#>   ALL_ABC ALL_CNN ALL_CNBC Love_ABC Love_CNN Hate_ABC Hate_CNN Love_CNBC Hate_CNBC
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       7       7        3        1        1        6        6         1         2
#> 2       6       5        5        3        3        3        2         2         3
#> 3      10       8        8        4        4        6        4         4         4
#> 4      11       7        7        6        2        5        5         5         2
#> 5       6       9        8        3        6        3        3         6         2
#> 6       8      14       14        2        7        6        7         7         7
#> 7      10       4       11        5        2        5        2         6         5
#> 8       4      12        5        1        6        3        6         3         2
```

The idea is to reshape it to make the sums easier. Then you can join the final result back to the initial dataframe.

- start by uniquely identifying each row with a `rowid`.
- reshape with `pivot_longer` so to have all values neatly in one column. In this step you also separate the names `Love/Hate_channel` in two and you remove the `Love/Hate` part (you are interested only on the channel) [that is what the NA does!].
- reshape again: this time you want to get one column for each channel. In this step you also sum up what previously was `Love` and `Hate` together for each `rowid` and channel (that's what `values_fn=sum` does!). Also you add a prefix (`names_prefix = "ALL_"`) to each new column name to have names that respect your expected final result.
- with `right_join` you add the values back to the original dataframe. You have no need for `rowid` now, so you can remove it.

Comment: Hey Edo, thank s a lot for this!! in theory this would be exactly what i want but i need to do it with uneven coefficient and for other new columns, so i would like to be able to write the formula for the sum myself and not just sum...

Comment: What does it mean "uneven coefficient"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `rlang`. Note, reshaping the data is likely more straightforward. Non-standard evaluation (NSE) is a complicated topic.

```r
for (channel in channels) { 
  DF <- DF %>%
    mutate(!!sym(paste0("ALL_", channel)) := !!sym(paste0("Love_", channel)) + !!sym(paste0("Hate_", channel)))
}
DF

##   Love_ABC Love_CNN Hate_ABC Hate_CNN Love_CNBC Hate_CNBC ALL_ABC ALL_CNN ALL_CNBC
## 1        1        1        6        6         1         2       7       7        3
## 2        3        3        3        2         2         3       6       5        5
## 3        4        4        6        4         4         4      10       8        8
## 4        6        2        5        5         5         2      11       7        7
## 5        3        6        3        3         6         2       6       9        8
## 6        2        7        6        7         7         7       8      14       14
## 7        5        2        5        2         6         5      10       4       11
## 8        1        6        3        6         3         2       4      12        5
```